# recursive function is not returning value in express js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am working in a ecommerce website. I have create a mongoose model for all categories. But including parent id for the category that is a subcategory.
when get a request send, all the categories are finding from database. That's fine but I want to send the category in a nested way to client. That's why I wrote like this.

```js
// This is mongoose model 


const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        unique: true
    },
    slug: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    parentId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
    }

}, { timestamps: true })

module.exports = mongoose.model("Category", categorySchema)



//   This is router


Router.get('/categories', async (req, res) => {


    const createCategory = (categories, parentId = null) => {

        const categoryList = []
        let category

        if (parentId === null) {
            category = categories.filter(cat => cat.parentId === undefined);
        } else {
            category = categories.filter(cat => cat.parentId === parentId)
        }

        category.map((cate) => {
            categoryList.push({
                _id: cate._id,
                name: cate.name,
                slug: cate.slug,
                children: createCategory(categories, cate._id)
            })
        })


        return categoryList
    }

    try {

        const categories = await Category.find({})

        const categoryList = createCategory(categories)

        res.status(200).json({ categoryList })

    } catch (error) {

        res.status(500).json(error)
    }
})

  // the data of databess
  
  [
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("613c4ae2ff0098e41b1ae89a"),
    name: 'Mobile',
    slug: 'Mobile',
    createdAt: 2021-09-11T06:21:22.137Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-09-11T06:21:22.137Z,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("613c4b11ff0098e41b1ae89c"),
    name: 'Oppo',
    slug: 'Oppo',
    parentId: '613c4ae2ff0098e41b1ae89a',
    createdAt: 2021-09-11T06:22:09.068Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-09-11T06:22:09.068Z,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("613c4b21ff0098e41b1ae89e"),
    name: 'Samsung',
    slug: 'Samsung',
    parentId: '613c4ae2ff0098e41b1ae89a',
    createdAt: 2021-09-11T06:22:25.359Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-09-11T06:22:25.359Z,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("613c4b2fff0098e41b1ae8a0"),
    name: 'Nokia',
    slug: 'Nokia',
    parentId: '613c4ae2ff0098e41b1ae89a',
    createdAt: 2021-09-11T06:22:39.048Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-09-11T06:22:39.048Z,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("613c4b47ff0098e41b1ae8a2"),
    name: 'Nokia 2.4',
    slug: 'Nokia-2.4',
    parentId: '613c4ae2ff0098e41b1ae89a',
    createdAt: 2021-09-11T06:23:03.580Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-09-11T06:23:03.580Z,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("613c4b6cff0098e41b1ae8a4"),
    name: 'TV',
    slug: 'TV',
    createdAt: 2021-09-11T06:23:40.550Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-09-11T06:23:40.550Z,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("613c4b7eff0098e41b1ae8a6"),
    name: 'Refrijerator',
    slug: 'Refrijerator',
    createdAt: 2021-09-11T06:23:58.782Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-09-11T06:23:58.782Z,
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

Them problem is when I trying to get data from client only root level category is outputting which has no parent id and but children array is empty like this.

```js
{
    "categoryList": [
        {
            "_id": "613c4ae2ff0098e41b1ae89a",
            "name": "Mobile",
            "slug": "Mobile",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "613c4b6cff0098e41b1ae8a4",
            "name": "TV",
            "slug": "TV",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "613c4b7eff0098e41b1ae8a6",
            "name": "Refrijerator",
            "slug": "Refrijerator",
            "children": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I think the "createCategory" recuresive function is not working.

please anyone help me I am new in this field...

Comment: If you're not using the result of `.map()` you should be using `.forEach()`

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem. When I try the  `children` array is populated. What is `categories`? Can you edit your question and provide sample data (in JSON format) for `categories` which gives you this undesired result?

Comment: You could use `.map()` if you write `categoryList = category.map(cate => ...)` and have the function return the object instead of pushing it.

Comment: Please output `console.log(JSON.stringify(categories, null, 2))` and include it in your question. I suppose the `_id` values are objects, not strings (which you seem to assume). But provide it, so we can reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `_id` properties are instances of `ObjectId`, they will never match with `parentId`, which are strings.

According to [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/#methods-and-attributes):

> `ObjectId()` has the following attribute and methods:
>
> | Attribute/Method | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | `str` | Returns the hexadecimal string representation of the object. |
> | ... | ... |

So change this line:

```
        children: createCategory(categories, cate._id)
```

to:

```
        children: createCategory(categories, cate._id.str)
```

### Remark

Your use of `.map` is an antipattern. You should take its return value and not use `push` in the callback. Replace these two statements:

```
    const categoryList = []
    /* .. */
    category.map((cate) => {
        categoryList.push({
            _id: cate._id,
            name: cate.name,
            slug: cate.slug,
            children: createCategory(categories, cate._id.str)
        })
    })
```

...with this single statement:

```
    const categoryList = category.map((cate) => ({
        _id: cate._id,
        name: cate.name,
        slug: cate.slug,
        children: createCategory(categories, cate._id.str)
    }))
```

Secondly, you can avoid code duplication at the start of your function, by just *not* providing a default value to the `parentId` argument. So that function can be become much more compact:

```
const createCategory = (categories, parentId) => {
    const category = categories.filter(cat => cat.parentId === parentId);
    return category.map((cate) => ({
        _id: cate._id,
        name: cate.name,
        slug: cate.slug,
        children: createCategory(categories, cate._id.str)
    }));
};
```

Comment: after Replace all I get an empty array. anything to do?

Comment: Yes, act on my comment below your question.

Comment: Thanks "trincot" to give me a clue and I find out by your clue. "cate._id" would be "cate._id.toString()"

Comment: You're welcome. However, if this didn't work, it means your `cate._id` are not `ObjectId` instances as depicted in your question. It would have been nice if you would have reacted to my comment on your question :/

Comment: sorry I am new I did not know mark would be change if I select another. I thought both would be marked. I think you have understood.

Answer (score 0):

change the code below

```js
 children: createCategory(categories, cate._id)
```

To:

```js
children: createCategory(categories, cate._id.toString())
```